# Is FeedMe v2 supporting FTP with basic authentication

Tags: plugin-feedme

I'm currently redoing a import mechanism for a site we've inherited.  I'm trying to use Feedme version 2 for this as opposed to the custom import script that was written (and is not working too well).

The import needs to be transferred via FTP with basic authentication.  I saw that version 1.4.7 included this FTP support and I'm wondering if that includes FTP with basic authentication and if that function is actually at all available in Feedme2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sake of completeness: the problem was that FeedMe was checking for statuscode 200 (http ok) instead of 226 that is used to determine a successful FTP transaction.

This has been fixed in the latest FeedMe 2.0.0 branch that can be found on https://github.com/engram-design/FeedMe/tree/2.0.0

Answer (score 2):

FTP should still work just fine in Feed Me 2. You can also use basic authentication by providing the username/password in the URL.

```
ftp://username:password@website.com/public_html/feed.xml
```

You can also use the `curlOptions` settings in the [configuration](http://sgroup.com.au/plugins/feedme/getting-started/configuration).